# Can't get to work Skrill Quick Payment API through the simple basic HTML Form?

Tags: php, forms, api, payment-gateway

I am trying to workout with a quick basic Skrill Quick Payment HTML form here but I am getting following error when I submit the form as :

```
Transaction not allowed
Wrong merchant email address!
```

Here is a Screenshot of the Error as :
[image: Skrill API Error]

While the form which I used for submission is as follows :

```
<form action="https://www.moneybookers.com/app/payment.pl" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="pay_to_email" value="<?php echo $skrill_email; ?>"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="status_url" value="<?php echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]".dirname($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]); ?>"/> 
  <input type="hidden" name="language" value="EN"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $_POST['amount']; ?>"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="USD"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="detail1_description" value="<?php if ($_POST['payment_type'] == 1) { echo "Donation"; } ?> Due Payment Invoice"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="detail1_text" value="<?php if ($_POST['payment_type'] == 1) { echo "Donation"; } ?> Due Payment Invoice"/>
 <input type="submit" value="Pay Through Skrill" alt="Skrill - Pay online, safely and easily.!" class="button">
</form>
```

Here is just a live output of the php form code :

```
<form action="https://www.moneybookers.com/app/payment.pl" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="pay_to_email" value="nicefellow1234@gmail.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="status_url" value="http://localhost/civicrm_development"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="language" value="EN">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100.00">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="USD">
  <input type="hidden" name="detail1_description" value="Donation Due Payment Invoice">
  <input type="hidden" name="detail1_text" value="Donation Due Payment Invoice">
 <input type="submit" value="Pay Through Skrill" alt="Skrill - Pay online, safely and easily.!" class="button">
</form>
```

Also it would be great if someone help me fix it or either give me a working form to workout with the their new Quick API Payment page.!

Comment: @PraveenKumar : No Problem.It's good to be cooperative with each other.Criticism always leads to doubtful results..!

Comment: @PraveenKumar : Well Brother..You and me,We all know that we are just here to help people to never give up in learning and to learn something new always and to build a profile..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For experimental purposes you can use their test form at https://www.moneybookers.com/app/test_payment.pl. To request a test account and test data, contact merchantservices@skrill.com.

For each currency there is a different email so you should check also if this email belongs to the specific currency (USD)

Comment: It's not working there either...! again the same error.!

Comment: As I said, you have to request a demo account and not make up parameters.

Comment: I've just tested your form with my account and its perfectly works. shows me the skrill customer login.

Comment: Well..My skrill account is personal not merchant type I think but It was working before and now it stopped working..!